# Escape glob pattern in command line arguments when running npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

Executing the following command fails in the latest versions of npm / node.
`npm run task-name --config baseUrl=xxx --spec "integration/test/!(A|B|C)/**"`

Error: `'B' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

The issue is caused by the pattern in the spec parameter.
npm changed the way command line parameters are processed here: [Github PR](https://github.com/npm/run-script/pull/78/files?diff=split&w=0)

How to escape that parameter nowadays correctly?

Comment: That's not a regex; it looks like an extended glob pattern.

Comment: True, sorry. Updated the description.

Comment: Globs in NPM are ran with `sh` in linux.

Comment: Extended glob patterns are not a feature of regular POSIX `sh`. They work if your shell is e.g. Bash (and has this feature enabled) but it is not portable. Without more context, it's hard to say what would be a good way forward. There really is no convenient way in standard `sh` to specify all files except a few in a single wildcard.